# Why i get None when i try to parse YouTube with BeautifulSoup python3

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I try to parse YouTube channels but i get nothing(None). I saw in stackoverflow about javascript cant be parsed, but this is 'div' in my browser elements watcher(is it script too?).

How to parse YouTube? (and yeah, there are no reason in `find` or `findAll`, anyway i get `None`)

Code:

```
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = Request('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNDdEl07a6oSH9MXueZdjiA/videos', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
# Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
# grabs main div with all videos
containers = page_soup.find("div", attrs={'class': 'style-scope ytd-grid-renderer'})
print(containers)
```

Result of code: `None`

Comment: What you are looking for ('div', 'class': 'style-scope ytd-grid-renderer') does not exist in the data you are receiving (I checked by printing page_html).

Comment: Hmm, thats interesting, this one is major issue. How and why page_html can be different than browser html

Comment: I'm not sure about Youtube, but some websites are created dynamically. You might have to use selenium webdriver for this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_dynamic_websites.htm

Comment: Very grateful to you. I think this one is answer to this topic